# iOS distinguish single tap and double tap at first opening

Tags: ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

I know that I can use `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` function to distinguish single tap and double tap, but I meet a tiny problem, and I want to fix it. My code is as below:

```
- (IBAction)singleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLOGD_METADATAONLY();
    hideNavigationBar();
    hideStatusBar();
    [sender requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.doubleTapRecognizer];
}

- (IBAction)doubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLOGD_METADATAONLY();
    //TODO
}
```

When I open a file and double tap(action1), single tap(result1) will be called firstly and then double tap(result2) will be called.

But if I open a file and single tap(action3), then double tap(action4), the result of action4 is working well,single tap will not be called only double tap will be called. I guess it is because in action3 the function `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` is called.

My question is HOW CAN I make action1 just call result2 and not call result1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the below lines in ViewDidLoad
 [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];

Comment: Sorry I made a fool mistake, I mistake pan gesture as single gesture, and now I fix it, thank you! I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code with `[singleTapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail: doubleTapRecognizer]` when you creating `UITapGestureRecognizer`

**Example:**

```
    // single tap    
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: tableViewController action: @selector(handleSingleTapOnView:)];                                 
    [singleTapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [singleTapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapRecognizer];
    [view addGestureRecognizer: singleTapRecognizer];

    // double tap 
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: tableViewController action: @selector (handleDoubleTapOnView:)];        
    [doubleTapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];         
    [view addGestureRecognizer: doubleTapRecognizer];
```

When you set `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` for a gesture recognizer, you're saying that it should only recognize the gesture if the other gesture recognizer did not.

Comment: I create the gesture in xib file, do you know where should I add the function?

Comment: then create IBOutlet for them

Comment: Yes I have created and I add singleTapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapRecognizer in viewDidLoad, but this set does not work.

Comment: Sorry I made a fool mistake, I mistake pan gesture as single gesture, and now I fix it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Extend your class as  `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
```

Then assign your view controller as delegate of gesture recognizer.

```
tapGesture .delegate = self;
doubleTapGesture .delegate = self;
```

Implementation of `shouldRequireFailureOf`  prevents the one gesture from being recognized until after the other gesture recognizer explicitly reaches the failed state.

You need to recognize a single tap only after the failure of a double tap, which happens when the touch sequence contains only one tap.
This can be achieved implementing following.

```
   func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
                   shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
// Don't recognize a single tap until a double-tap fails.
       if gestureRecognizer == self.tapGesture &&
            otherGestureRecognizer == self.doubleTapGesture {
          return true
        }
    return false
  }
```

Hope it helps.Happy Coding!!

Comment: Tried but still the same result.

Comment: you need not to call this method anywhere. This method is protocol method of UIGestureRecognizerDelegate check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate).  U just have to set your view controller as delegate of gesture recognizer.

Comment: I have updated my ans. Make sure to assign your view controller as delegate of gesture recognizer.